# Internal Server Error when making POST request using Rest Assured

Tags: java, rest-assured, web-api-testing

I tried to make a POST request using POJO but getting "vHTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error", could you please advise why?
When I pass body as string it works fine, but the passing the bookingDetails will throw the error. I think something is not right with the BookingDates class but I'm not sure why.

```
package bookings.POST;

import bookings.BookingBaseTest;
import io.restassured.RestAssured;
import io.restassured.response.Response;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;


public class CreateBooking extends BookingBaseTest {
    @Test
    public void createBooking(){
        //Set json Data
        BookingDetails bookingDetails = new BookingDetails();
        bookingDetails.setFirstname("Jim");
        bookingDetails.setLastname("Brown");
        bookingDetails.setTotalprice(111);
        bookingDetails.setDepositpaid(true);

        BookingDetails.BookingDates bDates = new BookingDetails.BookingDates();
        bDates.setCheckin("2018-01-01");
        bDates.setCheckout("2019-01-01");

        bookingDetails.setBookingDates(bDates);
        bookingDetails.setAdditionalneeds("Breakfast");


       Response response = RestAssured.given().
                                            spec(requestSpec)
                                            .body(bookingDetails)
                                        .when()
                                            .post();
        response.then().log().all();


    }


}
```

```
package bookings.POST;
/*
{
    "firstname" : "Jim",
    "lastname" : "Brown",
    "totalprice" : 111,
    "depositpaid" : true,
    "bookingdates" : {
        "checkin" : "2018-01-01",
        "checkout" : "2019-01-01"
    },
    "additionalneeds" : "Breakfast"
}
*/

public class BookingDetails {
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    private int totalprice;
    private boolean depositpaid;
    private BookingDates bookingDates;
    private String additionalneeds;

    //Omit other getters and setters


    public BookingDates getBookingDates() {
        return bookingDates;
    }

    public void setBookingDates(BookingDates bookingDates) {
        this.bookingDates = bookingDates;
    }


   static class BookingDates {
        private String checkin;
        private String checkout;

        public String getCheckin() {
            return checkin;
        }

        public void setCheckin(String checkin) {
            this.checkin = checkin;
        }

        public String getCheckout() {
            return checkout;
        }

        public void setCheckout(String checkout) {
            this.checkout = checkout;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I found where I was wrong. Here "private BookingDates bookingDates;" It should be bookingdates instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass the json serialized body of the BookingDetails object in your request body. You can use ObjectMapper for serializing the object:

```
//serialize the bookingDetails object 
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String bookingDetailsJson = mapper.writeValueAsString(bookingDetails);
```

And then pass it in your request body, also mentioning the contentType as JSON:

```
Response response = RestAssured.given().spec(requestSpec).contentType(JSON).body(bookingDetailsJson).when().post();
```

Comment: thanks for answering! As I commented above it was able to make it run by providing proper name but your solution is useful to me as well. Thank you!